# How to start writing to a text file 2 lines in

Tags: python

I’m currently opening a csv file and writing it to a new .h file. However, I would like to write everything BUT the first two lines of the csv file.

How can I start writing two lines in?

```
import csv
newheader2 = open("ffile2.h", 'w')
with open("pcf_gras.csv") as newcsvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(newcsvfile, delimiter= ',')
    newheader2.write("Heading Comment Section")
    for item in readCSV:
        #name = item[2]
        #newheader2.write(name)
        #print(item[2], item[5])
        newheader2.write("#define ")
        newheader2.write(item[2])
        newheader2.write(" ")
        newheader2.write(item[5])
        newheader2.write("\n")
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. If you want to know how to change your code to make that happen, we'll need to see it though.

Comment: Yes, i’ve been trying to upload however my picture won’t go through. I will keep trying.

Comment: Don't post a picture, just copy and paste your code as text! You can highlight it and click the `{}` button to indent it, which will make it display formatted.

Comment: Okay, I apologize this is my first time posting on here

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  I'm not down-voting; just giving you links for future posts.

Comment: This question looks ok to me now. It's certainly answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create your `readCSV` object, you can skip two lines by calling:

```
next(readCSV)
next(readCSV)
```

Then when you do `for item in readCSV:`, it will start from that position in the file.